# Griffon-JavaFX: View throws NPE concerning the model

Tags: java, model-view-controller, groovy, javafx, griffon

I am making a foray into the Griffon world, and I have a small lazybones application I downloaded that throws errors.  My view looks like so.

```
@ArtifactProviderFor(GriffonView)
class PennyPackerView {
FactoryBuilderSupport builder
PennyPackerController controller
PennyPackerModel model

void initUI() {
    builder.application(title: application.configuration['application.title'],
        sizeToScene: true, centerOnScreen: true, name: 'mainWindow') {
        scene(fill: WHITE, width: 200, height: 60) {
            gridPane {
                label(id: 'clickLabel', row: 0, column: 0,
                      text: bind(model.clickCount))
                button(row: 1, column: 0, prefWidth: 200,
                        controller.click())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

After using gradle:run, it throws an error that leads me to believe that my model isn't being injected, at least at the time the binding takes place.

```
Warning, could not locate neither a JavaFX property nor a JavaBean property for class         
javafx.scene.control.Label, property: '0'
[2014-10-20 13:30:56,166] [JavaFX Application Thread] 
  ERROR griffon.core.GriffonExceptionHandler      
  - Uncaught Exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot bind to null
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.bind(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
at javafx.beans.property.Property$bind.call(Unknown Source)
at groovyx.javafx.factory.FXHelper$__clinit__closure26.doCall(FXHelper.groovy:454)
```

Below is the model code, which isn't terribly complex.

```
@ArtifactProviderFor(GriffonModel)
class PennyPackerModel {
    @FXObservable String clickCount = "0"
}
```

Any help on why this NPE is being thrown or on any other issues is greatly appreciated.  I believe what I got from lazybones was the griffon-javafx-groovy starting app.

EDIT:  So I've been debugging, it looks like the model is being injected, but something is going wrong when setting up the binding.  In the StringPropertyBase class, the value of the newObservable being passed to it is null.

```
    public void bind(ObservableValue<? extends String> newObservable) {
    if (newObservable == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot bind to null");
    }
```

I don't know why this is happening, or how to fix it =(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line

```
text: bind(model.clickCount))
```

It should be

```
text: bind(model.clickCountProperty))
```

The first returns a plain value while the second returns a JavaFX property. I'm surprised you found this problem as a quick grep on the sources yields the following

```
$ grep clickCount -r griffon-javafx-* | grep bind
griffon-javafx-groovy-templates/templates/griffon-javafx-groovy/griffon-app/views/View.groovy:                          text: bind(model.clickCountProperty()))
griffon-javafx-groovy-templates/templates/subtmpl-artifact/View.groovy:                          text: bind(model.clickCountProperty()))
griffon-javafx-java-templates/templates/griffon-javafx-java/griffon-app/views/View.java:        model.clickCountProperty().bindBidirectional(clickLabel.textProperty());
griffon-javafx-java-templates/templates/subtmpl-artifact/View.java:        model.clickCountProperty().bindBidirectional(clickLabel.textProperty());
```